# Benchmarks comparing SSAS with SQL summary tables

Tags: sql-server, olap

Can anyone point me at a performance benchmark comparing SSAS with querying your own rollup tables in SQL?

What I'd like to understand is if the benefit from SSAS is entirely maintenance/convenience (managing your own rollup tables may become unmaintainable with a large number of dimensions) or if there is some magic in the MOLAP storage itself that makes it faster than equivalent relational SQL queries with equivalent pre-built aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

It's as much about the ease of slicing and dicing as it is storing the aggregations.  Sure, you can create your own rollup tables and subsequent queries that handles 10 different dimensions but I would rather use Excel/SSMS and just drag and drop.  I can also point my users to the cube and say 'have fun'.  I don't need to facilitate their every need, they can self-service.

As for the benchmark, that is dependent on your data warehouse schema, indexes, calculations, etc.  Basically, you would need to do the analysis yourself to see if it is better for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have link for that. But the rollup tables become complicated very soon as type and number of dimensions increase.

[This document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn749781.aspx) specifies the performance guide for MOLAP. Page 78 shows this diagram:

[image]

As you can see building the aggregate if you have hierarchies.